# Can $E=mc^2$ be used to find the energy stored in larger objects?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass-energy

I know that $E=mc^2$ can be used to find the total energy of a particle but can it also be applied to larger things? Say a chair with a velocity $0$ $\frac{m}s$ and rest mass $10$ $kg$? Would the total energy of the chair be $E=10\times(299,792,458)^2 = 8.98755179\times10^{17}$ $J$?

Comment: If it's at rest, yes.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. $c^2$ in the equation is just a dimensional coefficient to convert kilograms to Jiules. If you measure mass and energy in the same units (like electron-Volts), you can simply write $E=m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculated energy for the chair is correct.  However, you could only access this energy if you brought up an identical chair, composed of anti-matter wood, upholstery, varnish, etc. The two chairs would mutually annihilate, releasing twice the energy above, since twice the mass would be involved.

For a (slightly) real world example, consider a $3$ Gigawatt (thermal) nuclear power plant.

If it were to operate at this level for an entire year, it would generate:$$3\times 10^9 \times 86400 \times 365 \text{ joules}=9.46\times 10^{16}\text{ joules}$$
Dividing by $c^2$, we get $1.05 \text{ kilograms }$ of mass missing from the reactor fuel rods after a year of operation.

This amount of missing mass *might just* be detectable.  However, the loss of neutrons into the moderator and or cooling water could mask this $1$ kilogram loss